# Fatal error: Uncaught exception with message 'couldn't connect to host' in /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/

Tags: php, curl

**I am using Curl to connect to a server and update data using the following function. The function works great and updates approx 400 records. After that it throws an error, please advise how to solve this issue ?**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception  with message 'couldn't connect to host' in /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/

comm_Api_Connection->put('https://www.vam...', Object(stdClass)) #2 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/mysite/demo/comm-common1/Api.php(1530): 

comm_Api::updateResource('/products/5250', Array) #3 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/mysite/demo/sync_prod_inventory_new1.php(1088):

comm_Api::updateProduct('5250', Array) #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/mysite/demo/comm-common1/Api.php on line 204
```

**The PHP Function is as follows**

```
<?php
public function put($url, $body)
{
    $this->addHeader('Content-Type', $this->getContentType());

    if (!is_string($body)) {
        $body = json_encode($body);
    }

    $this->initializeRequest();

    $handle = tmpfile();
    fwrite($handle, $body);
    fseek($handle, 0);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($body));
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_exec($this->curl);

    return $this->handleResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a pinch I'd say you are opening too many connections to the server

Each time you call that method you open a new request, but don't close it.  It will stay open until the timeout is reached

If your server only allows 400 simultaneous connections, anything after the 400th call to the method will fail

You need to close your connections after each request

```
curl_close($ch)
```

Comment: I tried it like this 

curl_exec($this->curl);
                curl_close($this->curl);
  return $this->handleResponse();
 }

It didnt worked same error

Answer (score 1):

I think your curl need a SSL verification.

Please  put following line on your CURL code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This line is pass "true" is your request URL is HTTPS otherwise it's "false".

In your case i think it's true.
Please pass true parameter and check it.